# YouTube thinks that my server is in Germany but it's in the Netherlands

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, youtube, fedora

I'm trying to fetch pages from YouTube but YouTube shows a page saying that I can't watch the movie because it is blocked in Germany. The server is actually in the Netherlands (I checked in any location trace I found and all agree that it's in the Netherlands) but still all the pages show in German and it blocks me because of that.

I've checked the connection (fetched a page that shows your IP) and it showed the server's IP.

Does anyone know what the problem could be and how can I fix it?

---

This is the IP: `95.211.14.15` - I'm not sure about the DNS, the server located in Netherlands and I'm moving a website to this server and than pointing the domain using A Record.

The CNAME is defined on `2mp3.co.il` to that server (it's not pointing there) with A Record from the server to `95.211.14.15`. Why would it make any difference to YouHube from which CNAME it was called? And I don't know if it's matter - but the NS on the server pointing to `ns1/2.NCSB001.local`.

Comment: Fetching pages from a server most likely violates the YouTube terms and conditions.  You should rather use their embedded widget to have your visitors connect directly to the YouTube server.

Comment: But I need to get data from that page (and it's not available on the API)

Comment: Does the client machine (not the server) reside in Germany?

Comment: No, and the whole page loaded to the server so to Youtube it's like the server is browsing the site

Comment: Where is the DNS server you're using located?  It might go to a different server farm or cloud service.  This is complete speculation by the way.

Comment: This is the IP: 95.211.14.15 - I'm not sure about the DNS, the server located in Netherlands and I'm moving a website to this server and than pointing the domain using A Record.

Comment: It is worth finding out what DNS the server uses.  Some sites will work out your location from the CNAME->A name translation in DNS.

Comment: The CNAME defined on 2mp3.co.il. to that server (it's not pointing there currently) with A Record from the server to 95.211.14.15. why would it make ant different to Youtube from which CNAME it was called? And I don't know if it's matter - but the NS on the server pointing to ns1/2.NCSB001.local

Answer (score 1):

[Tell google](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/request.py?contact_type=ip&&hl=en) they've got incorrect information about your ip address (/network). We've had the same at our university and it got fixed within some days after we reported the problem (recognized as Switzerland instead of Germany).

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, but the problem is that's from a server I just bought and I need to place my site in it as soon as I can, and right now it's kind of a problem..